# Если вводить массив больше 5 или более чисел крашится программа, почему?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctime>
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL))
    int n;
    std::cout << "long? = ";
    std::cin >> n;
    float *arr = new float(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++ )
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
    std::cout << "original array:\n arr = {";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int u = i + 1;
        if (u == n) std::cout << arr[i] << "}";
         else std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7):

Потому что ваш код

```
 float *arr = new float(n);
```

Выделяет память под одну переменную типа `float` и инициализирует ее числом `n`.
Правильный код выделения памяти под массив:

```
 float *arr = new float[n];
```

не забудьте в конце программы освободить память:

```
delete[] arr;
```

Answer (score 5):

Если отвечать именно на этот вопрос

> Если вводить массив больше 5 или более чисел крашится программа

то причина следующая.

В этом предложении

```
float *arr = new float(n);
```

вы запросили память для одного объекта типа `float` и инициализировали его значением `n`.

Скорей всего размер объекта типа `float` составляет 4 байта ( `sizeof( float)` ). Однако система обычно не выделяет участки памяти такого малого размера. Обычно выделяются участки памяти, выравненные по параграфу (16 байт) и размером также в один параграф, то есть в 16 байт.

Поэтому если вы по ошибке напишите код

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++ )
{
    arr[i] = rand() % 100;
}
```

то вполне возможно, что программа будет работать без проблем, так как запись будет производиться в выделенный участок памяти. Хотя в любом случае на это полагаться нельзя, и следует рассматривать данную программу, как имеющую неопределенное поведение.

Поэтому конечно нужно исправить опечатку и написать правильно

```
float *arr = new float[n];
```

так как `n` может быть произвольным числом, а не только равным 1 или 4.

В этом случае вам перед завершением программы следует освободить выделенную память оператором `delete []`

```
delete []arr;
```

Следует также включить заголовок `<cstdlib>`, так как именно в этом заголовке объявляется функция `std::srand`

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

И лучше использовать квалификатор `std::` для стандартных C-функций, так как стандарт C++ не гарантирует, что эти функции будут помещены в глобальное пространство имен. Поэтому лучше написать

```
std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( NULL ) );
```

То же самое справедливо для функции `std::rand`

Цикл

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    int u = i + 1;
    if (u == n) std::cout << arr[i] << "}";
     else std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
```

можно было бы записать проще. Например,

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    std::cout << arr[i] << ( i == n - 1 ? "}" : " " );
}
```